# How would you make 50-100 HTTP requests per second in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am making a scanner where you give it an id and it checks that website for specific data. I'm trying to make it faster but can't figure out how.

Right now i'm using a web scraper and a SetInterval loop which runs at 10ms.

for some reason it only sends 5-10 requests per second. How do I make it faster?

(The requests are in parralel)

```
setInterval(() => {
  API(id) /// The function that calls the http request. 
  console.log(id)
  id++
}, 10);
```

Comment: Show your code, are the requests in series or in parallel? You should probably make the requests in parallel if possible, upto X simultaneous requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it asnychronous using something like:

```
let urls = [ 'http://....', .... ];

async function checkUrls (list) {
  let promises = []
  urls.forEach(u => promises.push(getUrl(e))
  return Promise.all(promises)
}

// run it
checkUrls(urls)
  .then(...)
```

Replace the getUrl function with a call to the fetching library you use like `axios` or `request`.

Comment: Thanks for the info but this won't work for what i'm doing.

My list of urls are infinite.

When someone uploads an asset to a website. I need to fetch the creator.

The website's asset upload rate is around 50 - 200 assets/s.

Comment: If you have a big or ever growing list of urls then better use `p-queue` which will provide you with a queue which you can further fill up while it is worked on in async mode. You can define the number of concurrent workers which define how much to do in parallel. Maybe you have to try the best setting for concurrent runs.

Comment: You find p-queue under https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-queue